# Add +1 In Front of Each Selected Row of Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update, prepend

I have a MySQL table containing 10 digit numbers. I need to add +1 in front of each via an UPDATE.

Let's say my SELECT statement looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM num_data
WHERE number REGEXP '^[0-9]{10}$'
```

How do I add +1 in front of each result of my query above?

Answer (score 1):

Use `CONCAT` to concatenate strings in MySQL.

```
UPDATE num_data
SET number = CONCAT('+1', number)
WHERE number REGEXP '^[0-9]{10}$'
```